# Access a Label via a DropDownlist_selectedindexchanged event , both in a Listview

Tags: c#, listview, drop-down-menu

is it possible to access the CouncilIdLabel via DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged event?!

```
<tr id="Tr10" runat="server">
            <td width="110px">
                دسته :&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="CategoryDropDownList" runat="server" Font-Names="tahoma" Font-Size="13px" onselectedindexchanged="CategoryDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Category") %>'>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="عمومی" Value="عمومی"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="پزشکی" Value="پزشکی"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="مددکاری" Value="مددکاری"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="روان شناسی" Value="روان شناسی"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:Label ID="CouncilIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CouncilId") %>' Visible="false" />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

it is located in a listview ItemTemplate

please help me, i need to solve this problem really soon

Answer (score 1):

You need to use FindControl on the ListViewDataItem itself. i.e.

```
Label coucilIdLabel = (Label)SomeListView.Items[SomeItemIndex].FindControl("CouncilIdLabel");
```

Or - In your selectedIndex changed event, this *should* work:

```
var item = sender.Parent as ListViewDataItem;
Label coucilIdLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("CouncilIdLabel");
```

Comment: the sender didnt have the "parent" member
so i used this

DropDownList CategoryDropDown = (sender as DropDownList);
        var item = CategoryDropDown.Parent as ListViewDataItem;
        Label coucilIdLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("CouncilIdLabel");

and it gave me this :  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: DropDownList CategoryDropDown = (sender as DropDownList);
        Control item = CategoryDropDown.Parent.FindControl("CouncilIdLabel");
        Label coucilIdLabel2 = (Label)item.FindControl("CouncilIdLabel");

i think this has solved the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  You'll have to find the control in the listview.  Use:

```
Label coucilIdLabel = (Label)MyListView.FindControl("CouncilIdLabel");
```

Comment: then how to access the text property?!

Comment: i have tried this and get this error
" Object reference not set to an instance of an object. "